# Swift: Pass Type as Parameter

Tags: swift, types, functional-programming

Is it possible to pass in a Type as a function parameter in Swift?  Note: I do not want to pass in an object of the specified type, but instead the Type itself.  For example, if I wanted to replicate Swift's `as?` functionality:

```
infix operator <-? { associativity left }
func <-? <U,T>(x:U?, t:T) -> T? {
  if let z = x as? t {
      return z
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, `t` is being pass in as a type, but I would like to pass in the Type itself so I can check against that type in the function body.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `T.Type`, but you have to cast as `T` and not `t`:

```
infix operator <-? { associativity left }
func <-? <U,T>(x:U?, t:T.Type) -> T? {
    if let z = x as? T {
        return z
    }
    return nil
}
```

Sample usage:

```
[1,2, 3] <-? NSArray.self // Prints {[1, 2, 3]}
[1,2, 3] <-? NSDictionary.self // Prints nil
```